# Truth-functionality of the "If-Then" connective in English

Tags: logic

A question in my logic class involves talking about the "if...then" connective in English and its mirror is sentential logic notation: the material conditional connective (denoted $\supset$).

The question is:

> It is uncontroversial that in an “if…then” statement in English, if the antecedent is true and the consequent is false, the conditional statement as a whole is false. But for every other possible combination of truth values, there are cases in which our judgments about an English sentence don’t neatly line up with what the $\supset$ definition delivers. This suggests that “if…then” is not a strictly truth-functional expression. Provide examples that illustrate that our judgments about English “if…then” statements don’t always neatly line up with what the $\supset$ definition delivers.

I'm having a hard time finding such examples, maybe because I assumed such statements in English were truth-functional and mirroring the material conditional connective $\supset$.

Any ideas on such English connective behavior?

Comment: "Typical" example: "if the moon is made of green cheese, then $2+2=4$". In truth-functional terms, it is *true* (conditional with *false* antecedent) but nobody in natural language will use a sentence like this and, if used, we will judge it at least "meaningless".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA has also written [a good answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14549/what-is-the-relation-between-the-material-conditional-in-logic-and-conditionals) explicating the problem on the Phil SE network.